# Imports Error In Visual Basic ASP.NET Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, iis

I am currently setting up a local environment of a project for which I was given only the source code. Having setup IIS7 and the site in it, I get the following error when  I visit the `localhost` in the browser:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type XXXLibrary.XXX_ObjectManager' is not defined.

    Source Error:


    Line 5:      Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    Line 6:  
    Line 7:      Dim xxxManager As XXXLibrary.XXX_ObjectManager
    Line 8:  
    Line 9:      Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

Having looked for something resembling `XXXLibrary.XXX_ObjectManager` name structure, I found a separate project(repository) called `XXXLibrary` with the following structure:

`XXXLibrary/ObjectManager/XXX_ObjectManagerMain.vb`

There are other `.vb` files there, but the `XXX_ObjectManagerMain.vb` contains the following class `Partial Public Class XXX_ObjectManager`, which, I believe, is the one my original project is searching for.

My question is how do I go about fixing this `imports` statement? My experience with VB and Windows technologies is quite limited, so I feel a bit like a  blind kitten trying to find my way around basic things.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the other project.

1) Right click your existing project in the Solution Explorer

2) Go to Add>Reference

3) Check the box next to your XXXLibrary project

Comment: Do you know what may be the cause of having this project work locally and throw this error when taken to production?